# How to add Attachment to an object in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online

I created attachments for some objects of a theme (as a File Geodatabase Feature Class) in  ArcGIS 10.0:  images (JPG) and doc files.

Then moved the same shp theme in my web-map of ArcGIS Online, and want to add in any way these attachments for these objects there as well. 
So, my main goal -  find a way to see this attached jpg and doc files when I choose concrete object in the web-map of ArcGIS Online.

Also I’d like to find opportunity to place in the web-map of ArcGIS Online  - URL in attribute table for any concrete object.

Could you advise me please – how it’s possible?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the widget Smart Editor on the Web AppBuilder. If your layer is FGDB and enables attachments, then you can add/delete.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to [configure the popup](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#/Configure_pop_ups/010q0000004m000000/).  They can [show attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#/Configure_pop_ups/010q0000004m000000/).
Then you will need to edit the layer and add attachments

Comment: I found this option, but met a problem, could you help me with this question?
In this page of  ArcGIS Online Help they wrote:

“Show attachments
Pop-ups can be configured to show attachments as links if the map includes a features layer that has attachments in its data. You will only see an option to show attachments if the layer has them. When the pop-up is displayed, the attachment links are listed at the bottom of the window. Clicking one of the links opens the attachment in a new window.
”
So – that actually what I need. But I don’t know how to attain that.

Comment: This text  means that I can browse a layer from ArcGIS with attachment??
But in ArcGIS I can add attachment only for File Geodatabase Feature Class. If I add attachment to it and then export it to a shp theme – it’ll lose these attachments (shp theme can’t have it as I understood).  Also I can’t browse File GDB as a zip folder in the web-map of ArcGIS Online.

Maybe I understood it incorrectly? What shall I do for browse theme WITH attachments to ArcGIS Online?

Answer (score 1):

Although this was asked two years ago, I'd like to provide a more thorough answer to this question, as there are a lot of views on this topic and the technology in ArcGIS Online (AGOL) has not changed much in the last two years since the original post *regarding Enabling Attachments for "Hosted" Feature Layers*.  Two of the options listed listed below will give you attachments in ArcGIS Online using Hosted Feature Layers. All of the options below assume you have an "Organizations Account" with ArcGIS Online and available credits.

If you upload your own shapefile (or a CSV) to AGOL, you will **not** be able to Enable Attachments once it is uploaded (aka Hosted) on AGOL.  Although you will be able to enable editing on this Feature Layer, enabling attachments is not possible.

If you upload a FGDB with a feature class that has attachments already enabled (eg. you have a Relationship class and Table for the attachments already created in the FGDB), you can upload this to AGOL and attachments will be enabled in AGOL after you've enabled editing on the Feature Layer in AGOL. You'll need to ZIP the FGDB before uploading to AGOL.

The last option (that I am aware of), is to use the [ESRI's ArcGIS Developers site](https://developers.arcgis.com/layers/#/) and create a new layer with Feature Editing and Attachments enabled there. Although you have to create your schema from scratch using their web interface, this will allow you to create a hosted Feature Layer with Attachments enabled in ArcGIS Online.